# React components api data disappears on page reload

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs

I have a list of components that retrieve data from an api. I noticed only on Safari if a user does 3 refreshes of the page, the data disappears and is no longer there. What could be the problem?

Comment: maybe browser cache that data...use hard reload and check again.

Comment: If you're not storing it in `localStorage`, `session`.. or loading it when the page loads then it will disappear after every refresh.

Comment: the data already persists but the reload issue is only on Safari